# How to send data to sever in iOS even when app is closed after every X interval of time in swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am trying to run some api call after every 10 minutes in my iOS app, I am able to do it when app is active, but how can I do same thing when app is inactive/closed. I have tried using silent push notification but failed. Can anyone guide me related that.

Comment: Read about [background app refresh](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/app_and_environment/scenes/preparing_your_ui_to_run_in_the_background/updating_your_app_with_background_app_refresh), but you can't rely on it since users can disable background app refresh, and the system decides when to call your app (e.g. it's disabled in low battery mode)